# ttgo t-beam and SPI for SD card problems

Tags: arduino, spi

I'm trying to find the problem with my code other than the simple, it doesn't work. The wiring all appears to be correct, and I'm suspecting a software problem, but I'm not having any luck finding it myself. I've also verified that the card is good and writeable.

```c
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// HSPI
#define HSPI_SCLK 14
#define HSPI_MISO 4
#define HSPI_MOSI 13
#define HSPI_CS 2

SPIClass * hspi = NULL;

String dataString =""; // holds the data to be written to the SD card
File sensorData;

void setup() {

  hspi = new SPIClass(HSPI);
  hspi->begin(HSPI_SCLK, HSPI_MISO, HSPI_MOSI, HSPI_CS); //SCLK, MISO, MOSI, SS
  pinMode(HSPI_CS, OUTPUT); //HSPI SS
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(HSPI_CS)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
  }

  if (SD.exists("data.csv")) {
    Serial.println("data.csv exists.");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("data.csv doesn't exist.");
  }

  // open a new file and immediately close it:
  Serial.println("Creating data.csv...");
  sensorData = SD.open("data.csv", FILE_WRITE);
  sensorData.close();

  // Check to see if the file exists:
  if (SD.exists("data.csv")) {
    Serial.println("data.csv exists.");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("data.csv doesn't exist.");
  }
  while(1);
}

void loop() {

}
```

This is running on the TTGO T-Beam. I'm specifying pins for SPI because the default pins aren't available since they're integrated with the LoRa chip. I'm not super familiar with using SPI, and this approach is new to me, but I've seen a lot of documentation for it online.

How can I figure out why I'm not reading/writing to my SD card?

Comment: "I'm specifying pins for SPI because the default pins" - what do you mean? You can't just use arbitrary pins, unless this is bitbanged implementation of SPI master. You also haven't told anything about the way this fails. I guess it compiles, and it's a runtime error? Are any debug messages printed on serial?

Comment: As I've been coming to understand it from documentation and other code libraries is that you can assign your own pins for SPI. If that's not correct then it sets me back to square 1 just figuring out which pins I can/should be using. The code does compile but I'm having no luck interfacing with my microsd reader/writer. I've checked the card and the wiring. I believe the problem to be code related.

Comment: Many times already told that SPI MMC is **ab**using SPI protocol. You really have to have a proper hardware and software support for this mode. And SPI bus physically allows you to connect devices in parallel. The CS (chip select) is what serializes access to them. Of course you have to think about impedance of the lines before adding many of the devices at high enough frequesncies.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a two part solution. The first issue was, even though the documentation stated that it could run on 3.3v or 5v, it only worked with the 5v line.

The second part was how I addressed the file. Once I added a slash in front of it, everything worked perfectly.

```
SD.exists("/data.csv")
```

I hope this helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

TTGO Tbeam V1
[image: TTGO Tbeam V1]

This is the T_beam I am using I tried to follow your code and I only just get errors saying no sd card and no file.

I read on here https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=708425.0 that these sd card readers sometimes need to be modified to work.

Did you have to do this?